# Map Not rendered Leaflet but renders correctly in changing the zoom level of browser

Tags: leaflet, rendering

I am loading a leaflet map rendering mapbox tiles, geojson layers (initially i dont show the map) and i also have tabular links which can be seen when the page loads, the links are list of places and when I click a certain location it opens the map and zooms to the coordinates associated with it. I used following to do so 
`<div id = "map"></div>
  <div id = "closeMapDiv">
    <button id = "closeMap">Close Map</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      $("#map").hide();
      $("#closeMap").hide();
      function showOnMap(a,b){
        $("#map").show("slow");
        $("#closeMap").show();
        // var loc = L.latLng(b,a);
        // var z = 7;
        // map.setView(loc, z);
      }
    </script>`

The function showOnMap is executed once we click the link, the result is something like this
[image: Can see tiles on the top left corner only].
The tiles can be seen on the top left corner only.

The strange thing is when i open the browser's console or change the zoom level of browser the map comes in right place. I must have done something stupid, i am unable to find out please help me figure out.
Here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/Poshan/dea760fb5207ac5ae5ec).

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes solution worked doing like this:.                        $("#closeMap").click(function(){
          map.invalidateSize();
          $("#map").hide();
          $("#closeMap").hide();
        });
        $("#closeMap").hide();

Answer (score 3):

Try to call map.invalidateSize() after changing the map div's size/visibility:
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-set-methods

Comment: Thanks @christoph looks like it works in some way. But still it is working only on second load of map i.e. only after I click the same link twice  or click another link. The first load is still showing same result.

Answer (score 1):

Just arraging the code so that the #map element gets styled before the JavaScript should solve the issue.